# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript

estoy aprendiendo a programar en javascript y recientemente me encontre con el siguiente problema : Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected to

lo que estoy intentando de hacer es crear de forma muy basica una pizarra en html que permita dibujar con cavas, hasta ahora esto lo he logrado todo , pero al momento de añadirle una paleta de colores a mi dibujo el programa deja de funcionar.

les dejo unas imagenes de la parte html de mi codigo y js para que puedan verla y si hay algun problema les agradezco sus correciones

```js
var estado = 0;
var paletas = document.getElementById(“Paleta”);
var color = paletas.value;
var pizarra = document.getElementById('area_pizarra');
var papel = pizarra.getContext('2d');
var ancho = pizarra.width;
var x;
var y;
document.addEventListener('mousedown', presionarMouse);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', soltarMouse);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', dibujarMouse);

dibujarLinea("color", 1, 1, 1, ancho - 1, papel);
dibujarLinea("color", 1, ancho - 1, ancho - 1, ancho - 1, papel);
dibujarLinea("color", ancho - 1, ancho - 1, ancho - 1, 1, papel);
dibujarLinea("color", ancho - 1, 1, 1, 1, papel);

function dibujarMouse(evento)
{
  if (estado == 1) {
 dibujarLinea(color, x, y, evento.layerX, evento.layerY, papel);
  }
  x = evento.layerX;
  y = evento.layerY;
}
function presionarMouse(evento){
estado = 1;
x = evento.layerX;
y = evento.layerY;
}
function soltarMouse(evento){
estado = 0;
x = evento.layerX;
y = evento.layerY;
}

function dibujarLinea(color, xinicial, yinicial, xfinal, yfinal, lienzo)
{
  lienzo.beginPath();
  lienzo.strokeStyle = 'black';
  lienzo.lineWidth = 3;
  lienzo.moveTo(xinicial, yinicial);
  lienzo.lineTo(xfinal, yfinal);
  lienzo.stroke();
  lienzo.closePath();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<htmL>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dibujando con el mouse</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Seleciona el color con el que deseas pintar
    <input type="color" name="Seleciona tu color" value="blue" id="Paleta"></p>
    <canvas id="area_pizarra" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
    <p>Dibiuja con el mouse lo que quieras</p>
    <script src="evento1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

pd : ya edite donde dice colorcito por color , y donde dice colorLinea tambien ya lo cambie a color y sigue sin funcionar, la r fue un  error que puse al poner la imagen, no estaba en el codigo original, y la llave extra tambien ya esta editado de la forma correcta

Comment: El código debe ir como texto, por favor lee  [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). ;)

Comment: Ahi tenes un "r" al final de la funcion

Comment: tienes una llave de cierre de mas tambien

Comment: @Israel-ICM , muchas gracias por informarme ya lo edite

Comment: @AugustoM fue un error al hacer la imagen, ya esta publicado el codigo original

Comment: @Christian fue un error al hacer la imagen, ya esta publicado el codigo original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está en esta línea

```
var paletas = document.getElementById(“Paleta”);
```

Deberías reemplazarla por:

```
var paletas = document.getElementById("Paleta");
```

Los caracteres que estás utilizando para las comillas dobles no son válidos, deberían ser `"` en vez de `“` o `”`, de resto tu código no da error y ejecuta bien

```js
var estado = 0;
var paletas = document.getElementById("Paleta");
var color = paletas.value;
var pizarra = document.getElementById('area_pizarra');
var papel = pizarra.getContext('2d');
var ancho = pizarra.width;
var x;
var y;
document.addEventListener('mousedown', presionarMouse);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', soltarMouse);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', dibujarMouse);
paletas.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    color = event.target.value;
});

dibujarLinea("color", 1, 1, 1, ancho - 1, papel);
dibujarLinea("color", 1, ancho - 1, ancho - 1, ancho - 1, papel);
dibujarLinea("color", ancho - 1, ancho - 1, ancho - 1, 1, papel);
dibujarLinea("color", ancho - 1, 1, 1, 1, papel);

function dibujarMouse(evento) {
  if (estado == 1) {
    dibujarLinea(color, x, y, evento.layerX, evento.layerY, papel);
  }
  x = evento.layerX;
  y = evento.layerY;
}

function presionarMouse(evento) {
  estado = 1;
  x = evento.layerX;
  y = evento.layerY;
}

function soltarMouse(evento) {
  estado = 0;
  x = evento.layerX;
  y = evento.layerY;
}

function dibujarLinea(_, xinicial, yinicial, xfinal, yfinal, lienzo) {
  lienzo.beginPath();
  lienzo.strokeStyle = color;
  lienzo.lineWidth = 3;
  lienzo.moveTo(xinicial, yinicial);
  lienzo.lineTo(xfinal, yfinal);
  lienzo.stroke();
  lienzo.closePath();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Dibujando con el mouse</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Seleciona el color con el que deseas pintar
    <input type="color" name="Seleciona tu color" value="blue" id="Paleta" />
  </p>
  <canvas id="area_pizarra" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  <p>Dibiuja con el mouse lo que quieras</p>
  <script src="evento1.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Para que el cambio de color te funcione necesitas revisar cada vez que el color del input se modifica, esto lo haces añadiendo un listener y actualizando el valor de la variable `color`

```
paletas.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
    color = event.target.value;
})
```

Finalmente tienes que usar ese color cada vez que realices un trazo en el canvas, ese color lo añades acá:

```
function dibujarLinea(_, xinicial, yinicial, xfinal, yfinal, lienzo) {
    lienzo.beginPath();
    lienzo.strokeStyle = color;
    lienzo.lineWidth = 3;
    lienzo.moveTo(xinicial, yinicial);
    lienzo.lineTo(xfinal, yfinal);
    lienzo.stroke();
    lienzo.closePath();
}
```

El caracter `_` normalmente se usa para ignorar un parámetro, en este caso ignoramos `color` que viene en la función para que no se sobreescriba con el color global.

Comment: quiero tener tus ojos °_°

Comment: Daniel me impresionas agradecido, apartir de ahora empezare a usar ' en vez de " ya que pueden pasar estas cosas, ya funciona como pizarra el problerma es que a la hora de cambiar el color en la paleta de colores no lo detecta, y colorea con el negro, muchas gracias por tu tiempo seguire investigando a ver como hacer que funcione

Comment: Si consideras que la respuesta fue satisfactoria te agradecería que la votaras como "La respuesta aceptada" :)

Comment: Acabo de añadir una edición con los cambios necesarios para que te funcione el cambio de color